# Swift/Firebase - Unable to retrieve data in order that it was entered?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

Having a problem retrieving data from Firebase in the same order that it was entered. I have tried this a number of ways using different variations of .valueAdded & .value to get this back in the same order but having no luck. Perhaps the way in which I am modelling this data is incorrect? Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

This is my Firebase Structure :

[image]

This is my data model:

struct RentalObjects {

```
var title = [String]()
var rentalType = [String]()
var dateAval = [String]()
var location = [String]()
var price = [String]()
var bond = [String]()
var pets = [String]()
var descripton = [String]()
```

}

This is my table view VC :

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class RentalTableViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var rentalImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var rentalTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rentalPrice: UILabel!


var rentalsObject = RentalObjects()
var databaseRef:DatabaseReference?
var handle: DatabaseHandle?

var arrayOfTitles = [String?]()
var arrayOfBond = [String?]()
var arrayOfDateAval = [String?]()
var arrayOfDes = [String?]()
var arrayOfLocation = [String?]()
var arrayOfPets = [String?]()
var arrayOfPrice = [String?]()
var arrayOfRentalType = [String?]()



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return rentalsObject.title.count

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")




    cell.textLabel?.text = ("Title: \(rentalsObject.title[indexPath.row]), DateAval: \(rentalsObject.dateAval[indexPath.row])")



    return cell
}


@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rentals")
    databaseRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            print(snapshot)




            switch snapshot.key {


            case "bond" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.bond.append(($0.value as? String)!)}
                //      print(self.arrayOfBond)


            case "dateAval" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.dateAval.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "description" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.descripton.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "location" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.location.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "pets" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.pets.append(($0.value as? String)!)}



            case "price" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.price.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "rentalType" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.rentalType.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "title" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.title.append(($0.value as? String)!)}
                print(self.rentalsObject.title)


                //       _ =  dictonary.map{self.arrayOfTitles.append($0.value as? String)}
                //    print(self.arrayOfTitles)

            default:
                break

            }

        }



        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }



    })

}
```

}

This is an example of the output from my tableView. I am trying to get this out in the same order it came in, in this example, 1,2,3,4,5. When I add in data from the other variables to this output they all become mixed up for some reason.

[image]

This is the code where the data is sent to firebase:

class AvertisingVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var rentalTypeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var priceField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bondField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var petsAllowedField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var detailedDescription: UITextField!



var databaseRef:DatabaseReference?   //reference to firebase dba


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rentals") //can add .child(string:root) to add root dir to dba
}

@IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func submitForm(_ sender: Any) {      // Send data to firebase on submit

    if titleField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("title").childByAutoId().setValue(titleField.text)
        titleField.text = ""
    }

    if  rentalTypeField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("rentalType").childByAutoId().setValue(rentalTypeField.text)
        rentalTypeField.text = ""
    }

    if  dateField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("dateAval").childByAutoId().setValue(dateField.text)
        dateField.text = ""
    }

    if  locationField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("location").childByAutoId().setValue(locationField.text)
        locationField.text = ""
    }

    if  priceField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("price").childByAutoId().setValue(priceField.text)
        priceField.text = ""
    }

    if  bondField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("bond").childByAutoId().setValue(bondField.text)
        bondField.text = ""
    }

    if  petsAllowedField.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("pets").childByAutoId().setValue(petsAllowedField.text)
        petsAllowedField.text = ""
    }

    if  detailedDescription.text != nil {
        databaseRef?.child("description").childByAutoId().setValue(detailedDescription.text)
        detailedDescription.text = ""
    }


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "You have successfully listed a rental", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: add the code in which you save your data

Comment: Ive added this to the main question - Thanks svi.data!

Answer (score 0):

When data is interpreted from network data, swift doesn't guarantee the order of the interpreted values if they're ordered in an array or dictionary. You'd have to order the values yourself, or update a cache device-side, and sort that cache each time it is updated.

There's many ways to this simply, or intricately for various use-cases. But looking at your's, i'd add a `sort` on wherever you're reading the tableView's datasource, before you call the `delegate` and `datasource` methods. Taking your example, if you sorted by date:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rentals")
    databaseRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            print(snapshot)

            switch snapshot.key {

            case "bond" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.bond.append(($0.value as? String)!)}
                //      print(self.arrayOfBond)


            case "dateAval" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.dateAval.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "description" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.descripton.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "location" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.location.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "pets" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.pets.append(($0.value as? String)!)}



            case "price" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.price.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "rentalType" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.rentalType.append(($0.value as? String)!)}


            case "title" :
                _ =  dictonary.map{self.rentalsObject.title.append(($0.value as? String)!)}
                print(self.rentalsObject.title)


                //       _ =  dictonary.map{self.arrayOfTitles.append($0.value as? String)}
                //    print(self.arrayOfTitles)

            default:
                break

            }

        }

        whateverCollectionIsYourInCacheDataSource = whateverCollectionIsYourInCacheDataSource.sorted(by: { ($0, $1) -> Bool in
            return $0 < $1 //If you want to sort them by their date value. Make sure the dates are properly interpreted from whatever format they're saved in remotely into the Date type.
        })


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //No need to call .reloadData and these methods in viewDidLoad, unless you REALLY have to (ie: your data is modified on purpose after being loaded initially). Calling these methods loads up the data anyways, so just call these whenever your data is downloaded, converted and sorted properly.
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.dataSource = self

        }



    })

}
```

Hope it helps you on the right path. Look up network-based tableview / collectionview tutorials, they can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks murphguy, will definitely look into the network-based tableview tutorials and using the sorted method you mentioned. My only issue is I need these arrays to be aligned, for example third element in the title array is related to the third element in the other arrays such as bond/price etc. All these properties are related to the single rental element. It looks like this may not be possible and I might have to rethink how I am modelling/storing this data?